# How do I redirect to www and https in settings.php?

Tags: 7, redirection, security

I want to include code in settings.php which would handle redirects to the www alias and also https.

Because it is for a distribution I would prefer not to have hard-coded URLs and I would also prefer not to be changing the .htaccess file so that core updates are easier.

I am using the code below, and I just want to be sure it doesn't have any security issues. Does it have any security issues, and I should therefore use different code?

```
// Redirect to www
  if (substr($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'], 0, 4) !== 'www.') {
  header('Location: '.$protocol.'www.'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].'/'.$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
exit;
}
// Redirect to HTTPS
  if($_SERVER["HTTPS"] != "on")
{
  header("Location: https://" . $_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"] . $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]);
exit();
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers! Notice that [tag:security] is not about using https://.

Comment: I take your point and thank you for the correction @kiamlaluno - my intent was to ask if the code is secure.

Answer (score 5):

The caveat to the **settings.php** approach is 2 issues:

1. Your redirect requires that Drupal be bootstrapped to work. If there's a resource that bypasses Drupal (e.g. any hosted files), you're not going to see the www redirect occur.
2. It's arguably bad practice. **settings.php** is for Drupal settings; depending on your intent this might be considered a *web server* setting. A developer working on your project in a local environment might have trouble understanding where the redirect is coming from as standard Drupal configurations use the **.htaccess** file for this.

An alternative to prevent **.htaccess** overwriting would to be place the rewrite directive in an Apache configuration (e.g. vhost.conf if you're using virtual hosts) that defines your host.

Comment: 1. An interesting point that I hadn't considered, however the intended use case would make this an unlikely scenario. 2. Fair point although it is an internal distro and would not be used by external devs. Lastly I should do some reading up on Apache config. Thank you for the tips @Shawn Conn.

Answer (score 1):

You can also choose to use the [htaccess module](https://www.drupal.org/project/htaccess) that allows these options with some radio buttons. It comes with Drush integration for re-deploying the .htaccess file after a core update, and monitors and warns if the file has changed. You might find it interesting.

From the module page:

> this module is dedicated to webmasters who don't want to manually
>   modify htaccess every time during a version upgrade to use Drupal.

Comment: Might this approach be more efficient than using settings.php?

Comment: @MrPaulDriver Not sure, I suppose apache will process `.htaccess` before bootstrapping Drupal and loading the settings. So rather than loading Drupal 2 or 3 times, it will load .htaccess 2-3 times and then attempt to load Drupal. So my guess would be this is better. I might be wrong though.